# why looping over string is different when it's in a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am wondering why when you iterate over a variable `n="1 2 3"` you get this:

```
$ n="1 2 3"; for a in $n; do echo $a $a $a; done
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

but if you don't put the string in a variable first you get a completely different behaviour:

```
$ for a in "1 2 3"; do echo $a $a $a; done
1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

or stranger yet:

```
$ for a in ""1 2 3""; do echo $a $a $a; done
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

why does it behave differently if a string is in a variable or not?

Comment: Because you're not quoting `$n` and your shell is doing word splitting. Try `n="1 2 3"; for a in "$n"; do echo "$a" "$a" "$a"; done`

Comment: [Worth a read](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/21233)

Answer (score 7):

```
n="1 2 3"
for a in $n; do        # This will iterate over three strings, '1', '2', and '3'

for a in "1 2 3"; do   # This will iterate once with the single string '1 2 3'
for a in "$n"; do      # This will do the same

for a in ""1 2 3""; do # This will iterate over three strings, '""1', '2', and '3""'.  
                       # The first and third strings simply have a null string
                       # respectively prefixed and suffixed to them
```